# Python for loop slows and evenutally hangs

Tags: python, for-loop, freeze

I'm totally new to Python (as of half an hour ago) and trying to write a simple script to enumerate users on an SMTP server.

The users file is a simple list (one per line) of usernames.

The script runs fine but with each iteration of the loop it slows until, around loop 14, it seems to hang completely. No error - I have to ^c.

Can anyone shed some light on the problem please?

TIA,
Tom

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Usage: vrfy.py <username file>"
        sys.exit(0)

#open user file
file=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
users=[x.strip() for x in file.readlines()]
file.close

#Just for debugging
print users

# Create a Socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Connect to the Server
connect=s.connect(('192.168.13.222',25))

for x in users:
        # VRFY a user
        s.send('VRFY ' + x + '\r\n')
        result=s.recv(1024)
        print result

# Close the socket
s.close()
```

Comment: Pretty advanced stuff for a noob. :)

Comment: Two notes though: `file.close` doesn't do anything, you want `file.close()` (and in the future, you should slowly get used to context managers), and the `.readlines()` call is pointless (you can just iterate over the file line by line as it is).

Comment: The problem? You're PISSING OFF THE SYSADMIN.

Comment: In case Ignacio's comment wasn't clear, it's likely that the sysadmin is intentionally slowing your connection because they think that you're a spam bot. See if it slows down if you do this in another language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely your SMTP server is tarpitting your client connection.  This is a defense against runaway clients, or clients which submit large volumes of "junk" commands.  From the manpage for Postfix smtpd:

```
   smtpd_junk_command_limit (normal: 100, stress: 1)
          The number of junk commands (NOOP, VRFY, ETRN or  RSET)  that  a
          remote  SMTP  client  can  send  before  the Postfix SMTP server
          starts to increment the error counter with each junk command.
```

The smtpd daemon will insert a 1-second delay before replying after a certain amount of junk is seen.  If you have root access to the smtp server in question, try an strace to see if nanosleep syscalls are being issued by the server.

Here is a trace from running your script against my local server. After 100 VRFY commands it starts sleeping between commands. Your server may have a lower limit of ~15 junk commands:

```
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fffda9a67a0)       = 0
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=9, revents=POLLOUT}])
write(9, "252 2.0.0 pat\r\n", 15)       = 15
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN}], 1, 300000) = 1 ([{fd=9, revents=POLLIN}])
read(9, "VRFY pat\r\n", 4096)           = 10
```

Comment: I don't (though I do have permission to poke at it :) ). Interesting thought though, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Easy to confirm by telnetting to the smtpd port and issuing the "VRFY user" commands by hand. If you notice responses getting delayed, this is a sure sign your server is tarpitting. Good luck!

Comment: Confirmed manually as you suggested. Exactly the same behaviour. It looks like the problem is as a result of the SMTP server's configuration rather than the script. Very well spotted and thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`s.recv` blocks so if you have no more data on the socket then it will block forever.
You have to keep track of how much data you are receiving.  You need to know this ahead of time so the client and the server can agree on the size.

Comment: @eat_a_lemon - Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why it seems to progressively slow down and stop... Based on your answer I would have expected the socket to block on the first iteration rather than slow down gradually...

Comment: @Tom well it depends on the rate that you are receiving data from the server.

Comment: I don't have the reputation for it yet I'm afraid... Will do if/when I do though :)

Answer (score 2):

Solving the exact same problem I also ran into the issue.
I'm almost sure @samplebias is right. I found I could work around the "tarpitting" by abusing the poor system even more, tearing down and rebuilding every connection:

```
#[ ...Snip... ]
import smtplib
#[ ...Snip... ]
for USER in open(opts.USERS,'r'):
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(HOST,PORT)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    verifyuser = smtpserver.verify(USER)
    print("%s %s:  %s") % (HOST.rstrip(), USER.rstrip(), verifyuser)
    smtpserver.quit()
```

I'm curious whether this particular type of hammering would work in a live environment, but too certain it would make some people very unhappy.

PS, python: batteries included.

Answer (score 1):

In a glance, your code has no bugs. However, you shall notice that TCP isn't a "message" oriented protocol. So, you can't use socket.send in a loop assuming that one message will be actually sent through the medium at every call. Thus, if some calls starts to get buffered in the output buffer, and you just call socket.recv after it, your program will stuck in a deadlock.

What you should do is a threaded or asynchronous code. Maybe Twisted Framework may help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: This isn't quite correct, there will be no deadlock. There are certainly problems with calling `.recv(1024)` (such as a response that is shorter or longer than expected), but deadlock won't be one of them.

Comment: socket.recv do not have any problem when reading less data than the present on the buffer, the remainder will still in the buffer, and can be read sometime after the first recv call. Maybe the OP may do an experiment: send all requests in the loop and read the input buffer after this. Or, to not lose any data, implement the program using threads. Logically, send us the result after.