# Testing a loop that repeats itself every 10 seconds

Tags: python, powershell, testing, python-requests

I have a code that repeats itself every 10 seconds, but I can't test it for a long time because my powershell keeps on hanging and the code just stops for no particular reason (the code is running but it doesn't give out results). Is there a way to test the code, or safely running it without it being interrupted? I tried to search but it seems that a library like `Unittest` will just crash along with my code due to windowshell if I want to run it for lets say a day. Because it usually hangs just a few hours after I start testing manually.

The code is something like this:

```
import time
import requests
while True:
    getting = requests.get(some_url)
    result = getting. json()
    posting = requests.post(another_url,headers,json=result)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Throw in some print comments then you'll have a better idea where it's dying.  Sounds like you might be running out of resources.. do you need to clean up some things (threads or connections)?

Comment: Check this bug: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/520  See how many sockets your app has open.  (That bug was fixed .. but that's the kind of problem I'd suspect you're having).

Comment: Another possible problem.. if you're not talking to a web server it might have anti-bot measures built into it (e.g. like this fellow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737336/python-for-loop-slows-and-evenutally-hangs)

Comment: I tried making it print something but it just stops. Sometimes it complete a loop and when I minimize powershell and come back in a minute I will find it just stopped. I am also writing to a text file and I am using `request.exceptions.RequestException` in case there's any error to make sure it goes on perfectly.
Regarding your first comment, can I do that? I am testing on my PC and it shouldn't run out of memory(i think?!). I will still need to check the other links you shared and I will report back. Thanks.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that I have the code running on Raspberry Pi and it could go on to up a month! But my PC it is hardly a few hours.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog as with regards to the anti-bot measures, I don't think the server has the same case as there are other devices that are sending to the server and they look fine.

Comment: Maybe its best not to run it in powershell or at least do not minimize it while the script is running.  Suggest running it in cmd.exe, IPython or Sypder.

Comment: @TrisNefzger thank you for your suggestions, sir. I actually tried cmd.exe and it gave me the same behaviour. I also tried the default IDE and it is the same. Maybe I will try IPython, Sypder or Pycharm.

Comment: Can you post whole code example if so I'll take a look.  I wasn't suggesting you were running out of memory.  More that you weren't cleaning up your network connections (specifically either the requests library wasn't, or you weren't freeing something for the garbage collector).  You have ton of memory, but only so many network connections.  It's good that you've replicated the problem outside of powershell.. you can rule that out as the cause of the problem.

Comment: Apparently the default number of sockets you can have open for windows is 64 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .. So you'd expect your app to stop after about 10 minutes if this is the problem.  (Don't quote me on the 64 .. it's bound to differ for different windows licenses and versions).

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to run it in a debugger in Spyder or some other IDE especially if you have an idea of where it faults so that a breakpoint could be set just before.  I would guess it goes out to lunch on a requests.get(some_url).  It may be useful to print the some_url and requests.status after each get or try logging them to a file in append mode.

Comment: If it's a resource problem you may want to use `perfmon` to monitor the process' counters while it's running and/or Process Explorer to keep an eye on the system load.

Comment: I am currently running the code on Pycharm and it has been running for around 11 hours now. So maybe this mean that running codes in PowerShell/cmd/Default IDE has a limited memory or something and thus the code is nullified after a certain amount of time or after some variant amount of steps (just a guess, not sure). While in Pycharm's case, this situation is handled in a better way? I am planning to keep for at least 24 to finalize the effectiveness and maybe try to identify the problem. If anyone has an idea then please share it.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog I understand what you mean. Pycharm seems to be able to handle the code at moment in a much better way, not sure why though. Btw, here's the code with more details. You can find the code a around the end by itshaddad. Not quite complicated but I am trying to optimize as much as I can. https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2693

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers please check my latest comments. I might be able to answer but it would a good idea to know why if you can help.

Comment: @TrisNefzger please check my latest comments. I might be able to answer but it would a good idea to know why if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after testing and experimenting. It seems like a resource miss-management by windows when I use PowerShell, cmd.exe or the default Python IDE. Thus in case someone wants to test their code for a prolonged period of time, it is recommended to use PyCharm as it has been running for more than a day for me. This should mean that PyCharm has better management in this specific area.

For more details check the comments under the question itself.

Comment: just answered you other question on timing.   Not this will not be doen every 10 seconds.   There will be 10 seconds wait between executing the three lines of code.  depending on your connection speed this might be considerable difference.  In your other question you were specific on exact timing of samples.    might not be relevant to your process here though?

Comment: It doesn't show here but I am compensating for the processes that happen within the loop, but even after that, some delay still exists, which is what I am trying to solve atm.

Comment: have you tried using urllib2 instead of requests?   might be problem with request cleaning up after itseld as well?   Not expert, but expect urllib to be able to do functions needed

Comment: I haven't tried tested urllib2 but I tried the code on a PC, and it gave me me awesome results for a few days (maybe a week?). So it might be a problem with the hardware of Raspberry Pi, although my code is just less than 100 lines! @Joop